# Can't get timer to count down

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer

I'm trying to learn how to use a timer in Swift, and every solution I look up is broken somehow or beyond my understanding.

I've tried with a closure, and without.

With a closure, I can actually get the app to run without crashing, but the timer just repeats `60`, it doesn't count down and I don't know why.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        var secondsRemaining = 60
        print(secondsRemaining)
        secondsRemaining -= 1
    })
```

I've also tried using an @objc func with selector, but my app crashes right away with error `Thread 1: "-[__SwiftValue countdown]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002970e40"` (I haven't even gotten to trying the count down yet).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(countdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        @objc func countdown() {
            print("fire")
        }
        …
        …
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

#### EDIT

If I place my variable outside the block, I get an error inside the block `Instance member 'secondsRemaining' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var secondsRemaining = 60
    
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            print(secondsRemaining)
            secondsRemaining -= 1
        })
}
```

But if I create a new project and put the timer inside `viewDidLoad()`, it works. I don't know why.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

var secondsRemaining = 60
    
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            print(secondsRemaining)
            secondsRemaining -= 1
        })
}
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't count down and I don't know why." I do. It's because that is what you told it to do. Every time the timer fires, you say `var secondsRemaining = 60; print(secondsRemaining)`. That means print 60. Every time.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your timer fires, a new variable with an initial value of 60 is instantiated, thus always printing 60.
You have to declare your counting variable outside:

```
private var secondsRemaining = 60

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in

    print(self.secondsRemaining)
    self.secondsRemaining -= 1
})
```

Or:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var secondsRemaining = 60

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(countdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
    @objc func countdown() {
        print("fire")
        self.secondsRemaining -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried declaring my counting variable outside, but I get an error that `Instance member 'secondsRemaining' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'`. I just created a new project and inserted my timer inside viewDidLoad() and it works. My original project doesn't have `viewDidLoad()`, and if I comment out `viewDidLoad()` in my new project it doesn't work there either. Should that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring counter inside the timer call. That's why every time the timer executes it resets the counter to 60 seconds. You need to declare your timer outside the it's call:

```
var secondsRemaining = 60

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        print(secondsRemaining)
        secondsRemaining -= 1
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, don't reset the variable every single time you get in the closure and change you timer to the following. Create a simple obj function to do whatever logic you want. Also name your functionalists meaningfully

```
class XViewController: UIViewController {
private var secondsRemaining:Int = 60

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(startScrolling), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


@objc func startScrolling() {
    print(secondsRemaining)
    secondsRemaining -= 1
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private  var secondsRemaining = 60

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            print(secondsRemaining)
            secondsRemaining -= 1
        })
    }
}
```